# Find DKIM and DMARC Records?

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim, dmarc

Is there a method to find a domain's DKIM and DMARC records using `dig` or `nslookup`?

I have attempted to do the following:

```
dig somedomain.org any
```

returns many records, but not the known DKIM and DMARC text records.

```
nslookup -type=txt somedomain.org
```

returns all the text records known except the DKIM and DMARC records.

Comment: DKIM records are applied to arbitrary subdomains (Google Apps uses `google._domainkey.example.com`) that you'd have to know/guess to look for.

Comment: It depends on the selector prefix used, part of the DKIM header in a signed email

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To query the TXT record for DMARC, you can use:

```
dig TXT _dmarc.example.org
```

To query for a particular record for DKIM, you would need to know the selector prefix. You will find it in the `s` value in an email's DKIM-Signature.

For example:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=example.org;
s=google; t=1615461277;
[…]
```

You would then query it as TXT:

```
dig TXT google._domainkey.example.org
```

Answer (score 13):

For DKIM records, if you have received a DKIM-signed email from that domain, look at the DKIM-Signature header line(s).

From the [spec](http://dkim.org/specs/rfc4871-dkimbase.html#keys):

> All DKIM keys are stored in a subdomain named _domainkey. Given a
>   DKIM-Signature field with a "d=" tag of example.com and an "s=" tag of
>   foo.bar, the DNS query will be for foo.bar._domainkey.example.com.

So in this example, you can then run:

```
dig TXT foo.bar._domainkey.example.com
```

Credit to andol, whose comment led me to this solution.

Answer (score 8):

You should use **+short** with dig to get the DMARC record only.

```
dig +short TXT _dmarc.domain.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows built-in tool `nslookup`

1. Open Command Prompt (cmd.exe)
2. Enter `nslookup`
3. Enter `set type=txt`
4. Enter `_dmarc.somedomain.org`, replace somedomain.org

Example:

```
C:\Users\user>nslookup

Default Server:  localdns
Address:  192.168.1.1

> set type=txt

> _dmarc.somedomain.org

Non-authoritative answer:
_dmarc.somedomain.org text =

    "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@somedomain.org"
```

You may use `server 8.8.8.8` (Google DNS) before lookup DMARC TXT record.

Comment: Wouldn't `nslookup -type=txt _dmarc.somedomain.org [8.8.8.8]` be simpler?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly query the [API at the registry.prove.email DKIM registry](https://registry.prove.email/api) via POSTing any domain, and then get any known selectors and current/historical DKIM keys back for about 7,000+ DKIM keys! So you wouldn't use dig or nslookup, you'd cURL the API instead. You wouldn't need to know the selector.